# How to set hash of a column in another column in flask-admin?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I want to save hash of name to hash_name column Also I use Flask-Admin to manage my data.

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode, unique=True, nullable=False)
    hash_name = db.Column(db.Unicode, unique=True)

admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))
```

Also I set default with uuid package for hash_name but this page in result had a problem .my uuid never changed . I refreshed but not changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only use flask-admin's SQLAlchemy ModelViews for editing, then it's possible to do following:

```
class UserView(sqla.ModelView):
    # Hide `hash_name` in list and form views
    column_exclude_list = ('hash_name',)
    form_excluded_columns = ('hash_name',)

    # Generate new hash on `name` change
    def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        if len(model.name):
            model.hash_name = generate_hash_name(model.name)
```

Otherwise use @mehdy's `event` approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use sqlalchemy's even listeners to manipulate your object before committing it to the database:

```
from sqlalchemy import event
...
@event.listens_for(User, "before_commit")
def gen_default(mapper, connection, instance):
    instance.hash_name = hash_function(instance.name)
```

so before each commit it will be invoked and updates the `hash_name` attribute with the proper hash on `name`